# Auto Increment Composite Key InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb

I want to create a MyISAM like behavior for an InnoDB MySQL table. I want to have a composite primary key:

PRIMARY KEY(id1, id2)

Where id1 auto increments based on the value of id2. What's the best way to accomplish this with InnoDB?

```
+----------+-------------+--------------+
|      id1 |         id2 | other_column |
+----------+-------------+--------------+
|        1 |           1 | Foo          |
|        1 |           2 | Bar          |
|        1 |           3 | Bam          |
|        2 |           1 | Baz          |
|        2 |           2 | Zam          |
|        3 |           1 | Zoo          |
+----------+-------------+--------------+
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Where id1 auto increments based on the value of id2."?

Comment: See the example data posted. That's the behavior I want.

Comment: You could do a lot of work to achieve something like this. It would be slow flaky and fragile. This should be two tables, or a single value key.

Comment: So id2 is inserted manually, and id1 increments only if there is a primary key collision?

Comment: Why do you want this behaviour?

Comment: Could be either way round actually. More importantly, why?

Comment: id1 is a message id, id2 is a chatroom id. I'd like for the first message in each chatroom to have an id of 1.

Comment: @CameronMartin I assume CaptainStiggz wants to avoid storing a unique int for every comment since the number can grow very large? Or maybe he is changing a MyISAM table to InnoDB and needs this to avoid having to change the code or tables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this BEFORE INSERT trigger to substitute zero id-values -

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON table1
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

  SET @id1 = NULL;

  IF NEW.id1 = 0 THEN
    SELECT COALESCE(MAX(id1) + 1, 1) INTO @id1 FROM table1;
    SET NEW.id1 = @id1;
  END IF;

  IF NEW.id2 = 0 THEN

    IF @id1 IS NOT NULL THEN
      SET NEW.id2 = 1;
    ELSE
      SELECT COALESCE(MAX(id2) + 1, 1) INTO @id2 FROM table1 WHERE id1 = NEW.id1;
      SET NEW.id2 = @id2;
    END IF;

  END IF;

END
```

Then insert zero-values (id1 or id2) to generate new values -

```
INSERT INTO table7 VALUES(0, 0, '1');
INSERT INTO table7 VALUES(0, 0, '2');
INSERT INTO table7 VALUES(1, 0, '3');
INSERT INTO table7 VALUES(1, 0, '4');
INSERT INTO table7 VALUES(1, 0, '5');
...
```