# How can this be done using an InnoDB table type?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following code that uses a MyIsam table type because of see the comment in the create code. How can this be done using Innodb.

Actually, a new article id is generated based on the user, and it starts from 1 for each user. However, this cannot be done if the table type is changed. How can this be achieved when using INNODB?

```
CREATE TABLE `articles` (
    `artcId` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `artcUserId` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `artcTitle` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'No title defined',
    `arctTime` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`artcUserId`, `artcId`)// See this part here and see the Image below.
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=myisam;
```

[image: ScreenCapture]

Comment: Can you run `SHOW TRIGGERS WHERE table='articles'`?

Comment: duplicate: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968879/auto-increment-composite-key-innodb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968879/auto-increment-composite-key-innodb)

Comment: @Norman Well, since the solution requires a trigger (as seen below) it's important to know what other triggers are there on the table.

Comment: There are no other triggers on this table.

Answer (score 0):

you can work with the trigger that is posted in the other thread or do it manually.

Pseudocode:

```
START TRANSACTION; -- needs to be in a transaction
...
SELECT @lastid := MAX(idItem) FROM item WHERE idArticulo = ?;
INSERT INTO item (idArticulo, idItem, texto)
VALUES (?, @lastid+1, ?);
...
COMMIT;

To handle the first-time situation:
MAX(idItem)
-->
IFNULL(MAX(idItem), 1)
```