# Determine cause of SQLConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, constraints

I am currently writing some code that works on updating values in a database. I have a table with three constrains: a primary key (composite), a foreign key (not composite), and a unique key (composite).

My table (the output of `show create table ItemAttributeMaster`):

```
CREATE TABLE `ItemAttributeMaster` (
  `SKU` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ItemAttributeID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Color` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Size` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SKU`,`ItemAttributeID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ItemAttribute_Unique` (`SKU`,`Color`,`Size`),
  CONSTRAINT `ItemAttribute_SKU` FOREIGN KEY (`SKU`) REFERENCES `ItemMaster` (`SKU`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**I have a trigger ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968879/auto-increment-composite-key-innodb) question) that makes the ItemAttributeID auto-increment as if it was an MyISAM table, so the primary key *shouldn't* be violated**

My code has the possibility of throwing an SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException. In that past, when I have had only one possible constraint violation exception (the foreign key), I assumed the SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException came from that constraint. But in this table, where I have two possible constraints that could be violated (the foreign key and the unique key), how can I tell which of these the SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException is referring to? Can I get the constraint type? Constraint name? Field names? I have scoured the web and JavaDoc, and can not find this.

Comment: If the error message doesn't say, you have to look at the values of the `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` statement that caused the error, and figure out which constraint(s) are being violated.

Comment: incidentally, _always_ include the _complete_ error message _verbatim_.  Very important.

Comment: @DanFarrell There is no error message per se, I am just trying to figure out my error-handling code. But I will take your advice to heart when posting future SO questions :)

Comment: @Andreas you mean I'd have to perform another query on the database? I hoped to do it without any more queries, but if that is the only solution...

Comment: Ah,I understand now.  The error you get doesn't specify the details.

Comment: The `java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` and the rest of JDBC do not provide you anything to determine which constraint, which columns or which values caused the exception. You either have to hope the message text itself provides sufficient information (which you'd need to parse), or if the driver itself has an extension for this (but AFAIK most don't).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Do you know a driver that does? This is just a hobby project, and I might be able to switch around the database because it's all on AWS RDS

Comment: Drivers providing such an extension? I'm not aware of any that do.